# How to change ibus input method shortcut to Shift+Caps Lock?

Tags: 13.10, keyboard-layout, ibus

I like how the different keyboard layouts are handled in Ubuntu - I can customize the switching keyboard shortcut to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, I can rig the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> keyboard LED to show the alternate keyboard layout...

But I find it much more convenient to use the ibus transliteration stuff instead of switching the keyboard layouts. I understand, that keyboard layouts are a completely different thing and entirely unrelated to the ibus stuff.

I'd like to mimic the keyboard layout handling behavior with ibus - specifically switching the input methods with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> (and as a bonus - rigging the LED to show if the alternate input method is active)

On `ibus-setup` I see no way to set the next input method as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>.

I tried the following values:

- `<Shift>+caps-lock`
- `<Shift>+CapsLock`
- `<Shift>+Caps`
- `<Shift>+Caps Lock`

The problem might be that I don't know how to spell the "Caps lock" properly for ibus...

Answer (score 4):

I guess the problem can be solved from the point of Linux Mint, where the `ibus-setup` application's capturing pressed key window is not broken.

The correct spelling is `Caps_Lock`...
[image]

Comment: I don't know how it worked for you, but for me one caveat is that when pressing my Shift+Caps Lock, it still toggles caps lock function (and light). So every time I switch layout I also toggle caps lock either on or off. So Caps Lock key is unusable for me in ibus. This might not be a problem if your only other layout is e.g. `ibus-mozc` which doesn't care about caps as much. Also maybe you can turn off your normal caps lock function.